# EFI/boot partition no longer recognized by UEFI/BIOS

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, uefi, arch-linux

**Context/Goal:**

I have my laptop that was dual-boot, one M.2 SSD for each machine (Windows and Arch Linux) and everything worked as it should. I bought a new higher capacity drive for my Windows machine, however each M.2 slot is a different form factor, so I removed the Arch drive and replaced it with the new drive, then cloned the smaller (in size and capacity) Windows drive onto it. I tested this cloned drive by itself and it loads windows fine.
Next, I replaced the new Windows drive back with the Arch drive in order to clone Arch onto the old Windows drive. The old Windows drive boots fine still, and the UEFI/BIOS recognizes that the old Arch drive is installed, but doesn't recognize its boot/EFI partition and gives no option to boot to it.

**What I've Tried:**

- Leaving the Arch drive as the only drive in the computer, says there is no boot option still
- Booted to Windows and looked at the partitions, which they seem intact and Windows says they're healthy

**Notes:**

- This Arch drive that doesn't boot is in the same M.2 slot as before
- I have a live boot USB of Arch if that makes this problem easier
- I'm using GRUB for my Arch bootloader

**TLDR:**
Arch drive was removed, replaced, and installed back in the same slot but no longer has it's boot partition recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Your previous installation wasn't recognized as the partition in general, but as a specific file – the `grub-install` tool created an NVRAM entry pointing to the exact path of grubx64.efi on that partition. Removing the disk might have caused the firmware to remove the NVRAM entry as "outdated".

EFI boot partitions don't always have a "default" bootloader that could be detected when the NVRAM entries are missing. Windows always installs one, but GRUB typically does not.

- Re-run `grub-install` from chroot like when you originally installed Arch, allowing it to re-create the NVRAM boot entry.
- Re-run grub-install, but use the `--force-extra-removable` option to additionally install a default bootloader to the EFI partition.
- Use `efibootmgr` to create the NVRAM entry manually.

  ```
  efibootmgr -c -L "Gentoo" -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l '\EFI\Arch\grubx64.efi'
  ```
- Use Windows `bcdedit` to create the EFI boot entry (Not a Windows Boot Manager entry) manually.

  ```
  :: Make sure the Arch EFI partition has a drive letter assigned
  :: (temporarily, for bcdedit only), e.g. Z: in this example.

  bcdedit /create /d "Linux Boot Manager" /application firmware

  :: Copy the GUID of the new entry that the /create command gives
  :: and substitute it in the following commands.

  bcdedit /set %GUID% device partition=Z:
  bcdedit /set %GUID% path \EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi
  ```