# Why can Debian 11 no longer load after Windows 10 changed motherboard state?

Tags: linux, windows-10, debian, uefi, secure-boot

Note that this question is not a duplicate of the typical dual-boot questions, because I never have the Windows-HDD and Linux-SSD at once in the PC, so they cannot touch each other's (efi) partitions.

On my ASUS board with the latest firmware, I have `Secure Boot` enabled, `Fast Boot` disabled, `CSM` disabled, *the whole time*.

1. I installed Windows 10 on the HDD, while having the SSD removed. In the Windows power settings, I disabled `fast startup`. All updates succeded. Power off.
2. Then I removed the HDD, connected the SSD, installed Debian `firmware-11.6.0-amd64-netinst` with a desktop. Worked fine. Updates succeeded. Power off.
3. Then I removed the Linux-SSD, connected the Windows-HDD again. I started Windows, autologin, start menu, power off.
4. Then I disconnected the Windows-HDD, connected the Linux-SSD again. When attempting to start the PC, I got `The current BIOS settings do not fully support the boot device. Click OK to enter the BIOS setup. Go to Advanced > Boot > CSM parameters, and adjust the CSM settings to enable the boot device.` But I do not want CSM since it was (and should be) working without it. GRUB of course does not show up. When I check the BIOS, my Linux-SSD does not show up as bootable, although visible in the SATA device list.

However I can connect my Linux flash drive, which is recognized as (UEFI) bootable, from which I can go to rescue-mode, mount the SSD, reinstall GRUB, and after that, my Debian 11 boots again from the SSD.

My suspicion was that Windows 10 writes/updates the secure-boot db/dbx, which my Debian 11 installation does not comply with. I read about some "BootHole" GRUB2 vulnerability, but that was fixed in 2020 already. And the [UEFI revocation list contents (see the csv)](https://uefi.org/revocationlistfile) does not have Debian related lines since 2020, just some others from 2022 september.

But then how can it be that my Linux flash drive still boots in UEFI mode but my SSD needs a GRUB reinstall for that?

Comment: might be related https://superuser.com/questions/1727663/efi-boot-partition-no-longer-recognized-by-uefi-bios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the SSD may cause some firmwares to automatically forget all NVRAM boot entries that used to refer to the now-nonexistent device.

This doesn't cause problems for Windows disks, which always have a copy of the Windows Boot Manager installed at the "removable" or "fallback" path, specifically `\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi` for x64 PCs. The EFI firmware will look for this specific path if it's told to boot a removable disk, or if it runs out of NVRAM boot options to try.

However, GRUB2 doesn't make that available by default – it only installs itself to its custom location (`\EFI\grub` or similar) and doesn't touch the "fallback" location.

Normally this could be solved by copying `grubx64.efi` to the fallback location, or by installing GRUB2 again with `grub-install --removable`, or with Debian's custom `--force-extra-removable` option. If you're using Secure Boot with Shim (default on Debian), then it's shimx64.efi that needs to be placed at this location instead.

This is a **temporary** solution. After getting the OS to boot again, I recommend removing the temporary BootX64.efi installation, as otherwise it will go out of date as new GRUB2 versions are installed (old GRUB2 kernel won't be able to load new modules from /boot).

For a permanent fix, re-run `grub-install` without any special options and let it create a new EFI boot entry in the motherboard's NVRAM. (You should then see it in the output of `efibootmgr`.)